# Is there any way of calculating the portion of signal lost as we keep on reducing the passband edge frequency of a band-pass filter?

Tags: filters, bandpass, snr

Any kind of references would be appreciable.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So, basically when we are passing of certain bandwidth through a BPF, it is coming out fine without any BER. But for some reasons, we need to reduce the passband (narrow down) of the BPF, and as a result, some portions are getting lost increasing the BER. So, is there any way to check how much portion is lost or any way to recover that.

Comment: Would you care to clarify what BPF and BER are? It’s good practice to define the acronyms you use. Plus, all additional clarifications belong to the body of the question if they make it easier to understand, so I strongly suggest you add them there.

Comment: BPF - Band-Pass Filter BER - Bit-Error-Rate